# Typescript error with assigning array of objects TS Error (2345)

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, t3

I'am using next.js with the T3 stack.

The error in the provided code is related to the type incompatibility when updating the solved state using the setSolved function. TypeScript is raising a type error because the code is trying to update the solved state with an array of { word: string[]; difficulty: number | undefined; title: string | undefined; }, but the solved state is of type ISolved[], which expects all items to have a number for the difficulty property.

```
interface ISolved {
  word: string[];
  difficulty: number;
  title: string;
}
const [solved, setSolved] = useState<ISolved[]>([]);
```

The Error occures here:

```
      setSolved((prevSolved: ISolved[]) => {
        const newSolvedItem = {
          word: selected,
          difficulty: data?.find((item) => item.wordString === selected[0])
            ?.difficulty,
          title: getDifficultyTitle(
            data?.find((item) => item.wordString === selected[0])?.difficulty ??
              0
          ),
        };

        return prevSolved ? [...prevSolved, newSolvedItem] : [newSolvedItem];
      });
```

Full code for this page is [here](https://github.com/1916eco/custom-connections-wordle/blob/main/src/pages/custom-game/%5Bid%5D.tsx)

I tried something like this before however this is obvious why it would have an error

```
      setSolved([
        ...solved,
        ...data?.sort((a, b) => a.difficulty - b.difficulty),
      ]);
```

the data has more attributes than the data as data has a structure of GameWords:

```
model GameWords {
    id          String @id @default(uuid())
    words       Word[]
    easyTitle   String
    mediumTitle String
    hardTitle   String
    trickyTitle String
}

model Word {
    id          String     @id @default(cuid())
    wordString  String
    difficulty  Int
    GameWords   GameWords? @relation(fields: [gameWordsId], references: [id])
    gameWordsId String?
}
```

Comment: The reason is you are assigning difficulty using an operating with the optional chaining operator, you need to either have a default fallback value like you are doing for the title, or change your interface declaration to number | undefined.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that actually, however, I did do a fallback and the error still persisted I did your second suggestion and changed the interface and all errors are gone. Thank you.